# How to calculate the memory space consumed when cache key store in c#?

Tags: c#, memorycache

How to calculate the memory space consumed when cache key store in c#

Comment: It's very difficult and inaccurate to determine how much memory a particular object is occupying in memory with .NET - there are a lot of factors at play that are implementation details. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: i just want when insert a cache key then i calculate how many space consumed that cache key..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a memory profiler that is a plugin for visual studio.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/04/04/net-memory-allocation-profiling-with-visual-studio-2012.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can find general information about the memory of your app by querying the garbage collector and cache object. I'm not sure how you can find the exact memory used by the cache, but this is a step in understanding memory consumption of your app.

```
// returns the memory consumption of this process
//  This includes active objects, objects to be disposed, and items within cache.
//  Setting the parameter to 'true' will force a garbage collection before returning the results
GC.GetTotalMemory(false);

// This shows the maximum size available to the cache
//  These limits can be set within the app.config / web.config files
Cache.EffectivePrivateBytesLimit;
```